# I am trying to compute the the tail of a future roll using the ratio of forward dv01

Tags: interest-rates, bond, futures, bond-futures

I am trying to compute the the tail of a future roll using the ratio of forward dv01, per the link [CME: Calendar Spreads with Tails](https://www.cmegroup.com/education/articles-and-reports/treasury-futures-calendar-spreads-with-tails.html) : I am trying to compute the the tail of a future roll using the ratio of forward dv01

There are multiple ways to construct this

Using the fwd dv01, But that fwd date can be back future date or front future date
E.g.   RXZ3 RXH4 roll

the dv01 for RXZ3 can be at Dec23 or Mar24,

so my question is how do i find the forward dv01 ( maybe approx using repo dv01)?